# how to validate username in paypal

Tags: paypal

Is there any way to use some paypal api for validation of username in paypal?

Google didn't give much :( and using [such](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/addressverify-api-operation-nvp) method isn't comfortable, cause there are too many requested parameters(for example, i know user's email, but i don't even want to know his adress,etc.).

Answer (score 1):

PayPal doesn't provide such an API and for a **very good reason**.

Remember - it's being constantly under a lot of pressure from scammers around the world that are trying to steal other people's money. Just imagine the phishing power one might get by being able to pre-validate the email addresses to see if they really are current PayPal users and then crafting a targetted email attack on them...

Such an API (to see if a random email address is registered with a PayPal account holder) does not and never will exist for security reasons. With possibly one exception - "trusted partners", where PayPal partners up with a big and established entity and allows special API permissions (based on secure credentials), but this is not something a mere mortal could ever hope for.

Furthermore, if a workaround is discovered that allows to do just that - rest assured PayPal will patch that hole ASAP to avoid security breach.